# one font, two texts, different characters

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm not new in HTML and CSS but right know i encoutred strange issue with fonts. I'm not able to show directlly my code, but I found out same issue on internet. The link is this:

[login page](http://infinite-woodland-5276.herokuapp.com/pages-signin-alt.html)

In top of this page, there is header

> PixelAdmin

, below is another header

> Sign in to your Account

If i inspect both of them, open computed tab and check font family, there is:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

But if I edit both of them and change their text with diacritic one, like this: ľščťžýáíéúäňô

in top one there is everything ok, while in bottom one there in font few chars are with another font...

How is it possible with same font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heading probably uses a different font weight. That weight may not contain all the accented characters, so font substitution occurs.